# How to define 'almost everywhere' on a smooth manifold.

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, lebesgue-measure, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f:M\to\mathbb R$ a (not necessarily smooth) function on $M$. Some time ago, someone came to me, showed me a certain such function, and claimed that it was smooth *almost everywhere*. I was not completely sure what this person meant.

**Question:** Does such a statement make sense? And if so, what exactly does it mean?

I'm basically wondering if there's a well-defined notion of 'almost everywhere' that applies  not to measure spaces but to smooth manifolds. If we were to define such a notion, the following seems the most natural to me:

We might say that a property $P$ holds *almost everywhere on $M$* if for any $p\in M$ there is a chart $(U,\varphi)$ on $M$, containing the point $p$, such that $P$ holds almost anywhere on $U$, evaluated with respect to the standard Lebesgue measure on $\varphi(U)$.

With this definition, we might hope to be able to prove a theorem that a property $P$ holds *almost everywhere on $M$* if and only if for any $p\in M$ and any chart $(U,\varphi)$ on $M$ containing the point $p$, $P$ holds almost anywhere on $U$, evaluated with respect to the standard Lebesgue measure on $\varphi(U)$.

Do these ideas make sense? Is there literature that discusses such notions?

Comment: Yes, your idea makes sense. The thing is that although there is no natural measure on a manifold, there is a natural notion of "measure zero": even though the pullback of the Lebesgue measure by two different charts on the overlap of their domains may not coincide, they are absolutely continuous with respect to each other, so a subset has measure zero for one if and only if it has measure zero for the other.

Comment: This is in Lee chapter 6

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In my edition of Lee, I found it in chapter 10, by the way.